# no se como hacer este codigo

Tags: python, lista

hola como esta tengo un problema con la realizacion de este codigo , la idea es que tengo con una lista de diccionarios en donde cada uno corresponde a un estudiante, y que tiene las llaves "nombre" y "nota" debo retornar una lista con todos los diccionarios actualizados con sus notas después de aproximación.
estos son los parámetros de aproximación
Si la nota es mayor o igual a 4.5, la nota se aproxima a 5.0.
Si la nota es mayor o igual a 3.5 y menor a 4.5, la nota se aproxima a 4.0.
Si la nota es mayor o igual a 2.5 y menor a 3.5, la nota se aproxima a 3.0.
De lo contrario, la nota asignada será 1.5.

```
def calcular_definitivas(estudiantes:list)->list:
estudiantes=[]
for nota in estudiantes:
    if estudiantes["nota"]>=4.5:
        estudiantes["nota"]=5.0
    if estudiantes["nota"]>=3.5 or estudiantes["nota"]<4.5: 
        estudiantes["nota"]=4.0
    if estudiantes["nota"]>=2.5 or estudiantes["nota"]<3.5:
        estudiantes["nota"]=3.0
    if estudiantes["nota"]==1.5:
        estudiantes["nota"]=1.5
return estudiantes
```

*texto en itálica*
alguien me podría ayudar a corregir mi codigo

Comment: Tienes una lista, no un diccionario, ese es tu error

Comment: seria debo cambiar donde dice estudiantes= [ ] por un diccionario ??

Comment: Sip, por que esto `estudiantes["nota"]` no es válido para una lista

Answer (score 0):

Para poder obtener una función como la que describes, pero interaccionando con una lista podrías utilizar éste código:

```py
def calcular_definitivas(estudiantes):
    resultado = []
    for indice, nota in enumerate(estudiantes):
        if 0 <= nota < 1.5:
            resultado.append(1.0)
        if 1.5 <= nota < 2.5:
            resultado.append(2.0)
        if 2.5 <= nota <= 3.5:
            resultado.append(3.0)
        if 3.5 < nota <= 4.5:
            resultado.append(4.0)
        if nota > 4.5:
            resultado.append(5.0)
    return resultado


grupo_1 = {
    "Arturo": 1.0,
    "Beto": 3.5,
    "Carlos": 2.2,
    "Daniel": 4.4,
    "Eduardo": 2.5,
}

calificaciones = list(grupo_1.values())

print(calcular_definitivas(calificaciones))
```

Que da como salida la lista `[1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 3.0]`

Aquí se genera una nueva lista llamada `resultado` que va añadiendo las notas redondeadas según las reglas de los intervalos, añadí código para cubrir los casos de los intervalos [0, 1.4] o [1.6, 2.4] para incluirlos.

También incluí un ejemplo de como podrías obtener los datos de un diccionario con los nombres y las calificaciones de los estudiantes, para pasar solo la lista de las calificaciones a la función.

## Versión de la función utilizando una lista de comprensión

```py
def calcular_definitivas(estudiantes):
    return [
        1.0
        if 0 <= nota < 1.5
        else 2.0
        if 1.5 <= nota < 2.5
        else 3.0
        if 2.5 <= nota <= 3.5
        else 4.0
        if 3.5 < nota <= 4.5
        else 5.0
        if nota > 4.5
        else None
        for nota in estudiantes
    ]
```